# My kafka consumer client doesn't work on my mac, why?

Tags: macos, apache-kafka

Hi: I'm new to kafka and I followed these steps to install and initialize kafka on my mac:

```
brew install kafka
```

I can see the config files are:

```
/usr/local/etc/kafka/server.properties
/usr/local/etc/kafka/zookeeper.properties
```

To start kafka

```
kafka-server-start /usr/local/etc/kafka/server.properties &
```

Create a topic named "test"

```
kafka-topics --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic test
```

I can list it:

```
kafka-topics --list --zookeeper localhost:2181
```

Start producer in one terminal and type some text:

```
kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test 
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/x/Documents/zk/server1/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.0.0/libexec/libs/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
>1st line
>
```

Start consumer

```
kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test --from-beginning
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/x/Documents/zk/server1/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.0.0/libexec/libs/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
```

Well the consumer doesn't print anything no matter what I enter in the producer terminal. How to trouble-shoot this problem, did I miss anything?

Comment: This should work, however, I typically use Docker on my Mac for working with it

Comment: stop producer after producing messages, they are still not visible on consumer side?

Comment: Instead of installing from homebrew, I would use un-zipped version and add aliases for kafka, zookeeper, consumer and producer, it helps to have multiple versions on same machine, also if there is issue with kafka, delete it and un-zip again.

Comment: Also add which version of kafka and java you are using?

Comment: try to start the consumer first and then the producer.The first time u run the consumer its registering with the group coordinator.

Comment: Start zookeeper first and then kafka

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download apache Kafka from: https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?path=/kafka/2.0.0/kafka_2.11-2.0.0.tgz

Unzip at any location and execute the following command in all terminals so that following command works, else you can replace the installation path in commands and execute.

`export kafka=<location-of-unzipped-directory>`

1. Run zookeeper by executing in above terminal `$kafka/bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh $kafka/config/zookeeper.properties`
2. Run kafka broker: `$kafka/bin/kafka-server-start.sh $kafka/config/server.properties`
3. Run Producer: `$kafka/bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test`
4. Run Consumer: `$kafka/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test --from-beginning`
5. Type anything in producer you can see output in consumer

Here is the image
[image: producer-consumer console]

Instead of remembering commands you can add following commands in .bashrc or .zshrc

```
export kafka="/Users/mac-user/standalone/kafka_2.11-2.0.0"
alias startkafka="$kafka/bin/kafka-server-start.sh $kafka/config/server.properties"
alias startzoo="$kafka/bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh $kafka/config/zookeeper.properties"
alias stopkafka="$kafka/bin/kafka-server-stop.sh"
alias stopzoo="$kafka/bin/zookeeper-server-stop.sh"
```

Comment: Well, this downloaded version works, while the brew installed version doesn't. Anyway, problem solved!

Comment: @cricket_007, yes, should be the same, did not try it so was not confident.